# OrderBy TimeOfDay not working

Tags: c#, linq

l.DateTimeRecorded contains a string with a DateTime. The FormatConverter returns a correct DateTime class.

But still the list is not properly sorted, what am I missing? The 'newest' item should be on top...

```
lines = lines.OrderBy( l => FormatConverter.FormatDateTime( l.DateTimeRecorded ).TimeOfDay ).ToList();

public static DateTime FormatDateTime( string dateTime )
{
     var dateTimeValue = DateTime.Parse( dateTime, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo( "en-US" ) );
     return dateTimeValue;
}
```

### Solution

The provided DateTime in l.DateTimeRecorded did not contain seconds.

Comment: If you want the newest first, it think it should be OrderByDescending since the newest date is the "biggest" value. But is there an other problem with your sorting? "Not properly sorted" is quite broad.

Comment: the problem is, that it is never sorted, neither by ascending nor by descending order

Answer (score 0):

OrderBy is sorting your values `ascending` order.There is another extension method named [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make descending sort:

```
lines = lines.OrderByDescending( l => FormatConverter.FormatDateTime( l.DateTimeRecorded ).TimeOfDay ).ToList();
```